# Display byte array in html without conversion to Base64 string

Tags: javascript, html, base64, client-side

I know that it is possible to display byte arrays as images in html after conversion to Base64 string as explained: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463981/displaying-a-byte-array-as-an-image-using-javascript)

Is it possible in html to display the raw byte array as Image without conversion to string?

Comment: a ByteArray is just a list of numbers without any internal meaning. What do these bytes represent? is this a file? are these the raw color-values, and how are they encoded/arranged?

Comment: Is [`canvas.putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) something that would be useful to you?

Comment: The exaple you linked to uses server code to convert to Base64 string. How would you get the byte array to client? I am assuming  don't want to do a conversion server side, the you could get an array via ajax call. Any data directly in html could also be in a `script` tag with the array information hard-coded. Then webgl could be used for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

the `window.URL.createObjectURL` [Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) creates a URL for the byte array image directly without conversion

```
var link = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
var image = document.getElementById("liveBox");
image.src = link;
```