# Caching images from Lorem Picsum

Tags: javascript

So, I want to use the very nice `https://picsum.photos/` to fetch a few random images and cache them for later user.

If I simply set the `src` of an image tag with `https://picsum.photos/id/493/200/300` - it works fine and dandy, but I wish to cache these images.

The content type of the request is `image/jpeg`.

I'm using `Axios` for my requests, so I grab `response.data`, but I'm not sure what to do next.

I've tried to put many thins in as the `src` of my `img`:

- simply `response.data`
- `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response.data)));`
- `data:image/jpeg;base64,${btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response.data)))}};`

Now I've ran out of ideas.

I guess my first problem is I'm not really sure what is being returned by the service. A byte array of said image? If I do `typeof` I get `string`, encoded byte array? Very confusing.

Here you can find the resulting `img` element: https://pastebin.com/9F0gnC7D

Comment: `image/jpeg;base64` requires data converted to base64. Where are you doing it? But this route seems like [the right one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9464137/223424).

Comment: @9000 I'm converting the data with `btoa`.

Comment: I wonder why you do `unescape(encodeURIComponent(response.data))` and not just `btoa(response.data)`.

Comment: @9000 because of this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223718/failed-to-execute-btoa-on-window-the-string-to-be-encoded-contains-characte

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240110/how-do-you-cache-an-image-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, the first important bit of information: If there is no `Content-Encoding` header in the response, it means that the endpoint returns the raw bytes.

The second and last piece: `Axios` returs a JSON, you can't put binary in JSON, so in the transformation to `string` it gets mangled, but there is a fix:

```
    fetchRandomPic: async (): Promise<any> => {
        const response = await Axios.get(URLS.RANDOM_PIC, { ...axiosConfig, responseType: "arraybuffer" });

        return `data:image/jpeg;base64,${Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString("base64")}`;
}
```

Works like a charm now :)