# How to display an image stored as byte array in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a web page in HTML/JavaScript. I'm downloading an image from my backend using AJAX. The image is represented as raw byte array, not an URL, so I can't use the standard `<img src="{url}">` approach.

How do I display the mentioned image to the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying byte array as image using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463981/displaying-byte-array-as-image-using-javascript)

Comment: OutputStream o = resp.getOutputStream();
o.write(imageInBytes);

Comment: I'm afraid to ask, but curiosity wins... Why is this off-topic?

Comment: I don't think this issue is off-topic.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Try putting this HTML snippet into your served document:

```html
<img id="ItemPreview" src="">
```

Then, on JavaScript side, you can dynamically modify image's `src` attribute with so-called [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

```
document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + yourByteArrayAsBase64;
```

Alternatively, using jQuery:

```
$('#ItemPreview').attr('src', `data:image/png;base64,${yourByteArrayAsBase64}`);
```

This assumes that your image is stored in PNG format, which is quite popular. If you use some other image format (e.g. JPEG), modify the [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) (`"image/..."` part) in the URL accordingly.

Similar Questions:

- [Displaying a byte array as an image using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463981/displaying-byte-array-as-image-using-javascript)
- [Display bytes as images on an .aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431095/how-to-display-an-image-stored-in-bytes-on-a-page)
- ['data:image/jpg;base64' and jQuery image preview in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820449/problem-with-dataimage-jpgbase64-and-jquery-image-preview-in-ie)
- [Convert from binary data to an image control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390983/convert-from-binarydata-to-image-control-in-asp-net)
- [How to convert a byte array into an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564119/javascript-convert-byte-to-image)

Comment: My Byte = dwr/download/k1a3JvBCfU3vLji$zKkhQObxzck.

src = data:image/png;base64,dwr/download/k1a3JvBCfU3vLji$zKkhQObxzck.

I used DWR

Comment: Byte Format image Download.

Comment: <b32ded4a 01000000 708de749 01000000 fa6a1102 01000000 e0e7e549 01000000 f0675d6f 01000000 c051db01 01000000 b23d1b8e  3a050000 00000000 30ea44c4  01000000 00000000 00000000 306b5d6f 01000000  0000>  Hi i getting data like this format can you help how to convert it into image data:video/webm;base64 format. It is actually a live video streaming.

Comment: Late to the party but if your response looks like `[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,...]`, you can use this line: `document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array([137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,...])));`

Comment: I edited the answer a bit to make it more clear, but I'm not getting one thing so I didn't really fix it. Why does this answer assume that the image is stored in a base64 string? The OP mentioned (and I checked the edit history) a "byte array", not "base64 string".

Comment: @ cubuspl42 It doesn't assume that image is stored in a base64 string. It is encoding the byte array into base64 encoded string so that <img> can view it

Comment: Joel, conversion from byte array to a string, the procedure `String.fromCharCode.apply` results in `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, so in my case, that's not an option.

Comment: In @Joel'-' solution, "btoa is deprecated" warning is given. If someone encounters the same issue, try using  `Buffer.from(array).toString('base64')` instead.