# extract last portion from url

Tags: javascript, url

Having the following link:
`/C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yyy\public\assets\1634648850202.jpg`

How do i extract `1634648850202.jpg`?

i tried:

```
const lastplace = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.lastIndexOf("\"));
```

This does not work, because the backslash is recognized as a functional character (is this the right term?)

Here are 2 Questions from my side:

1. how do i extract the last part?
2. how should i handle backslashes in general?

Comment: This is a literal backslash: `"\\"`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37896292/4202224

Comment: `const splitedValues = thisUrl.split('\'); 
const lastplace = splitedValues[splitedValues.length-1]`

Comment: Your problem is not only the not escaped backslash in `lastIndexOf` but also the inability of JS to parse the backslashes in your string. So you would need to escape these in the string itself befor doing something with it

Comment: replace \ with / then basename it

Answer (score 1):

Common way:

```js
thisUrl.split(/\/|\\/).pop() // 1634648850202.jpg
```

I also recommend to split url/path by both slashes (`/`,`\`) 'cause of different enviromnents/systems uses diffrent character.

UPD: just make your `\` double to handle it (you're right, it's a escape character), like this:

```js
''.lastIndexOf('\\')
```

Also you need do the same when you initiate your string:

```
const thisUrl = '/C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\yyy\\public\\assets\\1634648850202.jpg';
```

Comment: @empiric sure, what's the thing I missed?

Comment: @empiric Er, that's because the string the OP gave didn't fully escape all the `\` characters, not because of anything contained in this answer.

Comment: @empiric sure, I had to clarify here also need to escape slashes during initialization. Thanks !