# Angular 2 - render byte[] from Web Api as an image src

Tags: c#, angular

I have an Angular 2 app that is connecting to a Web Api backend.
There is an endpoint that returns a byte[] of an image that is stored in a sql database.
How can I display this as an image in Angular? 
I can change either the Web Api or Angular app.

My Web Api endpoint looks like this...

```c#
[Route("api/profileimage/{userId}")]
public byte[] Get(string userId)
{
    var image = _profileImageService.GetProfileImage(userId);

    return image;
}
```

And my Angular HTML looks like this...

```html
<img src="http://localhost:2116/api/ProfileImage/{{tile.UserId}}" width="100" height="100"/>
```

What conversion do I need to do, or what should the api serve up?

Comment: this may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756042/javascript-how-to-display-image-from-byte-array-using-javascript-or-servlet

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Convert the image to Base64 on your server:

```c#
[Route("api/profileimage/{userId}")]
public string Get(string userId)
{
    var image = _profileImageService.GetProfileImage(userId);

    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(image);
}
```

For ease of use I created a new directive to encapsulate all the code we need for getting and displaying the image:

```ts
import {Directive, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS, DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Directive({
  selector: '[profile-image]',
  providers: [BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS],
  host: {
    '[src]': 'sanitizedImageData'
  }
})
export class ProfileImageDirective implements OnInit {
  imageData: any;
  sanitizedImageData: any;
  @Input('profile-image') profileId: number;

  constructor(private http: Http,
              private sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {        
    this.http.get("http://localhost:2116/api/ProfileImage/" + profileId)
      .map(image => image.text())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.imageData = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
          this.sanitzedImageData = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageData);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

In your template include it like this:

```html
<img [profile-image]="tile.UserId" width="100" height="100" />
```

> Don' forget to add the directive to the `directives` array of your
>   component.

---

> Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AsK4SpWmBTt3D8EYSlB4?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: Thanks for that, its not quite working though. I see blank images and get this error in the browser, I don't think the endpoint is being reached... WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value data:image/png;base64,[object Object]

Comment: In the HTML the src looks like this... src="unsafe:data:image/png;base64,[object Object]"

Comment: Okay, I researched this issue and it has some quirks to it - I will update my answer in a few seconds.

Comment: Great, thank you, I'm still playing with it but don't have an answer yet.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting closer. I'm seeing an net::ERR_INVALID_URL error in the browser now.

Comment: I don't know how the WebApi returns the string, but you could try `map.json()` instead of `map.text()`, if it's not plain text.

Comment: Ah yes that's it! Thank you!

Comment: No problem - glad I could help you. Learned something new today, too! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117101/discussion-between-ben-cameron-and-rinukkusu).

Comment: in my case I got this error - 
imageData:1 GET http://localhost:4200/imageData 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 15):

[So the accepted answer by rinukkusu is very helpful & detailed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324958/7588447) **but you don't have to:**

1- Neither make a directive (but you can of course)

**2- Nor to use the sanitizer service & make an sanitization exception**

I was a little bit overwhelmed by those two tasks, especially bypassing the sanitization, so I will write the simplest way to handle this safely

**You can simply use the following method (in generic way):**

1- Return the image from your backend as base64 encoded string

2- Recieve that base64 string of the image in Angular 2+ & build the following string property in your typescript file then safely use it in your html directly without using the sanitizer service

```
// so for example you will get the image for example in this dataService.ts

this.http.get(this.api_url + 'image').subscribe(response => {
    this.image = response['image'];
    this.imageSrc = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.image;
});
```

Then in your html file , you can use the imageSrc property directly (for example from the injected dataService that have the property ready)

```
<img id="image" [src]="dataService.imageSrc" width="100" height="50">
```

I hope this helps someone else & many thanks for rinukkusu as his answer helped me personally