# Angular 2 disable sanitize

Tags: angular, typescript, sanitization, angular2-template

I am trying to render base64 string into `<img src='data:image/png;base64,${Here}'`.

But always when I try to render it, ng2 sanitizing my base64 string before rendering it adds something into my value before showing it in DOM.
I have found workaround(using DomSanitizer) but it doesn't work on latest versions.

Here is my markup:

```
<img alt="RegularImage" src="data:image/png;base64,{{imgBase64}}">
```

And here is my component part:

```
imgBase64="SomeBase64StringFetchedSomehow";
```

But angular2 is showing in console next message - `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value`

How to prevent NG2 from sanitizing my base64 string?

**Update**

```
get getImg() {
    return this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL,`data:image/png;base64,${this.img}`);
}
```

Doesn't solve this issue. DomSanitizer class does not exists anymore in RC6

Comment: Why are you not using final instead of RC.6?

Comment: Just tryied with RC.7 and release version of angular2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After few hours of researches I have finally found that in latest version of ng2 there is no `DomSanitizer` that can be injected using DI, however there is `Sanitizer`. So here is the usage:

```
constructor( private _sanitizer: Sanitizer){
}

get getImg() {
    return this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, `data:image/png;base64,${this.img}`);
}

<input src="{{getImg}}"/>
```

As you can see first argument of `sanitize` method is `SecurityContext` instance, which basically is enum. So right now `Sanitizer` is a factory which choose the implementation to use based on `SecurityContext`

In my case I had a problem that my base64 was sanitized before that get, that why I was not able to get it working.

Answer (score 9):

You need to explicitly tell Angular2 that the string is trusted

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html

```
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {}

get imgBase64() {
  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/png;base64,$SomeBase64StringFetchedSomehow');
}
```

```
<img alt="RegularImage" [src]="imgBase64">
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Comment: There is no DomSanitizer class anymore. I was trying to use new one - `Sanitizer` but it failed with same error.  

`return this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL,`data:image/png;base64,${this.img}`);`

Comment: Of course there is. Check the link in my answer (import info is at the bottom of the site). (Previously it was named `DomSanitizationService`)

Comment: Module '".../node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'DomSanitizer'

Comment: As I mentioned above it was renamed. I guess in RC.7 so you probably need to use `DomSanitizationService` or perhaps `DomSanitizerService` (don't remember exactly) (or update to final)

Comment: I have tried with RC7 version and release version of Angular2 and still there is no `DomSanitizer`/`DomSanitizationService`/`DomSanitizerService`. However there is `Sanitizer`, but it is not working. I am still getting - `ARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value data:...`

Comment: `Sanitizer` should work as well. `DomSanitizer` is the concrete implementation you get passed, but you don't need to know about that. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324762/angular-2-render-byte-from-web-api-as-an-image-src and there it seems to work.

Comment: Not sure why some people say it doesn't work. It works fine in Angular 8

Answer (score 4):

After unsuccessfully trying to get the bypassSecurityTrust... functions to work, I resorted to the following:

```
@ViewChild('div_element_id') private div_element_id: ElementRef;
...

this.div_element_id.nativeElement.innerHTML = bypass_security_for_this_html;
```

Comment: Oh, my.  No.  This should never be done.  Bypassing sanitazation leaves you open to XSS attacks.

Comment: Not if the html is trusted, for example, it was created in a CMS.