# angular2 show base 64 image

Tags: angular, base64

My api returns a string like following:

["/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7AARRHVja3kAAQAEAAAAPAAA/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAAAf/bAIQABgQEBAUEBgUFBgkGBQYJCwgGBggLDAoKCwoKDBAMDAwMDAwQDA4PEA8ODBMTFBQTExwbGxscHx8fHx8fHx8fHwEHBwcNDA0YEBAYGhURFRofHx8fHx8fH -- string continues-- gFAKAUAoD//Z"]

If I paste this string in http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter, I can see the image.

To handle this on my angular2 frontend I have a service:

```
fetchGallery(id: number){
        return this.http.get( this.myUrl + id + '/', {withCredentials: true})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response)
    }
```

I call this service from one of my components:

```
fetchGallery(id: number){

        this.galleryService.fetchGallery(id)
        .then( 
            response => {
                this.gallery = response;
                console.log(this.gallery)
            });
    }
```

And on my html:

```
<button (click)="fetchGallery(specific_hall.gallery)">Show images</button>

<div *ngFor="let image of gallery">
    <img [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,' +image ">
</div>
```

I get status 200 Ok, However I can not see any image on my UI. Looks like there are no errors.

One more thing, for this specific string I am sure I am going to get JPG, but otherwise when we are not sure weather the returned string could be a JPG or PNG, how can that be handled? The complete string:

```
["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"]
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524536/angular-2-disable-sanitize/39524574#39524574

Comment: I did not get any sanitizer error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `response.json()` to get access to the response payload.