# Ionic 2 : "WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value" error

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, ionic2

I work in Ionic 2 and I want to display a picture with variable, somethink like this :

```
<img src="data:{{user.file.type}};base64,{{user.file.content}}"/>
```

But the picture isn't display on my bowser and I have this error in the chrome console : "WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value"

Howerver, when I put my file type and file content in hard code it's work. But I need to use variable.

Any idea ? :)

Comment: You probably need a sanitizer like demonstrated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/39524574/217408

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this happens but it can be prevented by creating a binding to the src

`<img [src]="'data:'+ user.file.type +';base64,'+ user.file.content "/>`

[Plunker demonstrating the effect](https://plnkr.co/edit/su8PJiJ0slEWkfvqOuBm?p=preview)

In case that for some reason you don't want to/can't click the URL:

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there is no difference whether `[src]="expr"` or `src="{{expr}}"` is used.

Comment: I've solved this issue on multiple occasions just by creating the binding. It doesn't show any errors in the console when binding to the `src`

Comment: Oh. well in that case the code is correct? In case the media type is in the correct form

Comment: I think using a sanitizer is the way to go. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39524574/217408

Comment: Why does this occur? Is it a browser related issue? Since the plunker works

Comment: Actually I don't know. I would expect the same behavior.

Comment: Figured that having a space in the base64 image, or missing a single letter/wrong  base64 string/wrong media type returns in a unsafe html warning.

Comment: @V.Pivet you accepted my answer? What was the solution?

Comment: It was an error in my base64 code. Your solution with [src] work ! :)

Comment: aaah okay that explains. Your own code would work as well probably.