# ionic v2 display images from internet

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to display images from my ionic app in in a similar fashion to the below:-

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Blah/ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>   
    <div id="image">
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

and in my typescript file, I write the following:-

```
LoadImage(hash, id){
   document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="'+ img_URL + '" />';       
}
```

However, using this method ends up with the image link being broken, and in debugging with js, a 403 error pops up. what is the correct method to display an image from an external source?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try a more angular way of approaching this instead of the `document.getElementById`

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div [innerHtml]="myImage">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And then

```
public myImage: string;

// assume the parameters are neccessary in real code but not for MCVE
loadImage() {
   this.myImage = '<img src="'+ img_url + '"/>';
}
```

Pluker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WBeRRJyYucLwvckjh5W7?p=preview

So, sadly, after taking a look at one of your images, the response was

> "The owner of this site does not allow hotlinking"

Which means that this image cannot be embedded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that did not solve my problem, I am afraid.

Comment: Well, check the plunker. With the code you provided, this solution works. Else, if you still have a `403` on your image, which means 'forbidden', you can't embed it for some reason. Can you give your imageUrl or are the images on local network or do they violate privacy?

Comment: Well, the image links do work. And the funny part is, when I load them from the link itself, then the images start to load from that point onwards.  Is it something to do with accessing native functionalities, cause I am trying to set up this approach anyways, and it is nopt working unfortunately.

Comment: Well I'm not sure, you're not showing that you're accessing native functionalities. But do you mean that, when you start your application you see no images, but when you manually enter a URL that the images will then start loading?

Comment: Well, I have not used native functionalities at the moment, I have only used the direct method, which, in this case, doesnt work.

Edit:- Yes, that is exactly what happens.

Comment: Can you post an image link? Or is it unreachable/classified?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134059/discussion-between-adniwhack-and-ivaro18).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the **automatic sanitization** of the URLs by angular.

you can read about it here : https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

this is already answered in
[Angular 2 disable sanitize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524536/angular-2-disable-sanitize/39524574#39524574)

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for answering. However, the above problem occurred due to the fact that the server did not allow resource hotlinking. To factor that, I made a script to download the image from the server and then display the image.