# Bind translateX() transform in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, binding

How can one bind the `transform: translateX()` style in Angular?

What I've tried:

```html
<div [style.transform]="translateX({{x}})">
```

and

```html
<div [style.transform.translateX.px]="x">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work

```
<div [style.transform]="'translateX(' + x + 'px)'">
```

**Edit**

It seems that it is necessary to bypass [XSS protection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#bypass-security-apis) for this to work.

Comment: Added to the answer

Comment: I tried to sanitize with bypassSecurityTrustStyle but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524536/angular-2-disable-sanitize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524536/angular-2-disable-sanitize)

Comment: Don't disable sanitisation. Put the style declaration on the typescript `@Component` and reference it. `<div [@mystylename]>`

Comment: @RJFalconer can you explain it in more details or give me a reference to that feature? thanks

Comment: @RJFalconer we need your help! can you provide more info or some link to explain more? thank you

Comment: I know this is possible as I ran across the same issue before. I will see if I can dig out what I did. Sorry for being [That Guy](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 0):

```
[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'translateX(' + transX + 'px)'}"
```

where `transX` is a component variable.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works but you can make you code a lot cleaner by using methods as the binding of your style properties

```html
<div *ngFor="let il of imageLayers">
    <img class="divFloatLayer" 
        [src]="il.img_src" 
        [style.left]="il.getLeftPx()"
        [style.top]="il.getTopPx()"
        [style.z-index]="il.getZindex()"
        [style.transform]="il.getTransform()"
    />
</div>
```

In the class that contains the values that you need to bind to:

```js
getLeftPx() {
    return `${this.left}px` ;
}

getTopPx() {
    return `${this.top}px` ;
}

getZindex() {
    return `${this.z_index}` ;
}

getTransform() {
    return `translateX(${this.x}px)`;
}
```

Comment: Does this have equal performance to the accepted answer?

Comment: how many times are you going to call it in 1 minute ? feel free to compare and let us know.