# Angular 2 ngStyle and background-image

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

I have a big trouble with Angular 2 ngStyle directive. I can't set background image from base64 encoded file. Now in template.html I have this:

```
  <div class="projects_item_wrap" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+images[i].file+')'}">
```

Where 'images' is an array of base64 encoded .png files and their names.

Console.log of images[3].file give me this (trouble not inside an image, it works perfectly when I use it in img src='...'):

[image: blob image]

Any ideas? Thanks a lot for answers! :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: If you mean domSanitizer - I have already try it - nothing changed :(

Comment: Alternative `[style.background-image]="'url('+images[i].file+')' | safeResourceUrl"` (where the pipe uses `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value)`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524536/angular-2-disable-sanitize

Comment: Tried to add pipe - no result. Also tried to add sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle() - same, no result.

Comment: What about `...TrustUrl()`

Comment: Here is a screenshot where you can see makeTrustedStyle and pipe: https://prnt.sc/gh0tv1

Comment: What about `...TrustUrl()`

Comment: Here I tried to user ...TrustUrl() - http://prntscr.com/gh0z9d

Comment: I already tried to use them both (...TrustStyle and TrustUrl) - you can see result on previous screenshot.

Comment: Did you try `trustUrl` with `[style.background-image]="myUrl"`? As you see in the questions I linked, it worked for others.

Comment: Ofcourse. Here is used method: https://prnt.sc/gh178l And here is result: http://prntscr.com/gh17wd Tried to use pipe (...TrustUrl, ...TrustStyle) - same, no result. In Chrome dev. tool style is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linebreaks within received base64 image was a reason of trouble.
This is my solution:

```
//This goes to template <div>:
[style.background-image]="makeTrustedImage(images[i].file)"

//And this goes to component:
constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

makeTrustedImage(item) {
    const imageString =  JSON.stringify(item).replace(/\\n/g, '');
    const style = 'url(' + imageString + ')';
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, Not working