# Angular 6 - render byte[] from Web Api as HTML5 Image

Tags: html, angular, image

I implemented [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324762/angular-2-render-byte-from-web-api-as-an-image-src) in my Angular application and it is working fine.

But business made a decision to only return byte and not as base64 and wants to display on HTML5 image.

My image type is IFF.

How can I display bytes returned by Web API as HTML5 image for IFF file type

Comment: I don’t believe html can render iff format images... generally I’ve only ever seen like photoshop be able to?

Comment: Not sure what your photoshop comment is.

Comment: I said, I’ve only ever known photoshop or other image editing software to be able to render iff format images

Comment: @bryan60 As I said, I am able to display IFF image as base64. I would like to do it as HTML5 image

Comment: Then just load it like any other image if this works? Assuming the headers are correct it should be fine, all files are sent as byte arrays. Are you sure you don’t mean tiff?

Comment: @bryan60 I used base64 before to load the same image and now I don't want to use base64 and wants to render as html5 image and it is not working.