# How to convert a byte array into a jpeg image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, sockets, server

I currently have a java client sending pictures in the form of byte arrays to a node.js server. Once it receives this data, I want to be able to convert the byte array back into an image file(e.g. image.jpeg) and save it to the disk. How would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756042/javascript-how-to-display-image-from-byte-array-using-javascript-or-servlet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : How to display image from byte array using Javascript or Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756042/javascript-how-to-display-image-from-byte-array-using-javascript-or-servlet)

Comment: I would prefer documentation of node.js follow this link https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback