# Displaying an image from a json file

Tags: java, json

I need to display an image from a JSON file, but I can't find anywhere how to do it. Can anyone help me? This is an image from a tiled map I need to display in a GUI. I've tried looking for a solution online but I can't find anything. I've included the JSON file below.

```
{ "height":32,
"infinite":false,
"layers":[
{
 "data":[27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27],
 "height":32,
 "name":"Grass",
 "opacity":1,
 "type":"tilelayer",
 "visible":true,
 "width":32,
 "x":0,
 "y":0
}, 
{
 "data":[433, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 434, 411, 437, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145, 146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145, 146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 418, 437, 0, 294, 271, 271, 271, 271, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 271, 271, 271, 271, 294, 0, 418, 437, 0, 294, 271, 271, 271, 271, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 131, 0, 0, 130, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 271, 271, 271, 271, 294, 0, 418, 437, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145, 146, 0, 0, 145, 146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 161, 0, 0, 160, 161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 130, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 131, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 145, 146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145, 146, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 160, 161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 161, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 130, 131, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 130, 131, 0, 418, 437, 0, 145, 146, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 145, 146, 0, 418, 437, 0, 160, 161, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 160, 161, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 130, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 131, 274, 274, 130, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 131, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 274, 274, 145, 146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145, 146, 274, 274, 145, 146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145, 146, 274, 274, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 130, 131, 274, 274, 160, 161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 161, 274, 274, 160, 161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 161, 274, 274, 130, 131, 0, 418, 437, 0, 145, 146, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 145, 146, 0, 418, 437, 0, 160, 161, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 160, 161, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 131, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 130, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145, 146, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 145, 146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 418, 437, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 161, 0, 0, 274, 274, 0, 0, 160, 161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 418, 445, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 274, 274, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 432],
 "height":32,
 "name":"Bomen",
 "opacity":1,
 "type":"tilelayer",
 "visible":true,
 "width":32,
 "x":0,
 "y":0
}, 
{
 "data":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 293, 293, 293, 293, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 388, 389, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 368, 369, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 388, 386, 1610613125, 1610613125, 1610613125, 1610613105, 1610613125, 1610613105, 1610613125, 1610613105, 1610613125, 371, 371, 1610613105, 1610613125, 1610613125, 1610613125, 1610613125, 1610613125, 1610613125, 1610613125, 1610613105, 386, 389, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2684354934, 1610613104, 1610613124, 1610613124, 1610613124, 1610613104, 1610613124, 1610613104, 1610613124, 1610613104, 1610613124, 391, 391, 1610613104, 1610613124, 1610613124, 1610613124, 1610613124, 1610613124, 1610613124, 1610613124, 1610613104, 1610613124, 374, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225861, 3221225860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3221225841, 3221225840, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 "height":32,
 "name":"Road",
 "opacity":1,
 "type":"tilelayer",
 "visible":true,
 "width":32,
 "x":0,
 "y":0
}],
```

Comment: look here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20756091/3959856

Comment: I need java, not javascript

Comment: One thing is not clear: do you need help on how to interpret the data, or do you need help on how to write the code converting the data to a more conventional format for images?

Comment: ok, so you are using Swing or JavaFx?