# How to pass the File as URL in REST API response for view the document directly

Tags: java, rest, http, web

I have a GET REST API which accepts empno in request and returns the document in response. Right now we are passing the response as ResponseEntity. But when   the client hits the URL then this documents gets downloaded from my API call. Below is my sample code:

```
public class ViewDocController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{empno}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> viewDoc(@PathVariable(value = "empno") String empno)
            throws ServletException, IOException {      
        return baseBiz.viewDoc(documentRequestBody);
    }
}
```

But we want that instead of downloading, the file should open in the browser when we hit on the API URL. For example, if in my api url is:
http://localhost:8080/rest/services/viewDoc/12345
then on hitting this on explorer, the file should open on the page.

Please suggest any way to do this

Comment: Used "inline" in Header content-disposition and opened the OutputStream to write the bytes. response.setHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));
  response.setContentType(contentType.toString());

Answer (score 0):

You can send back object with byte array like this,

```
public class ExistingFileDAO extends BaseMessage {

    String fileName;
    byte[] targetArray;

    public ExistingFileDAO(String fileName, byte[] targetArray) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.targetArray = targetArray;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public byte[] getTargetArray() {
        return targetArray;
    }

    public void setTargetArray(byte[] targetArray) {
        this.targetArray = targetArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: After getting byte array. you can follow below link to display image, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756042/javascript-how-to-display-image-from-byte-array-using-javascript-or-servlet

Comment: I cant make any changes in the front end side. There is some other api in php which can send the file back directly so that it opens in the browser directly. I need to implement the same way.