# convert array buffer to image in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i send a request from server for get image .

this is my request :

```
downloadImage(id: number): Observable<any> {
console.log('in service ')
return this.http.request('GET', this.appConfig.apiEndpoint + '/Post/DownloadFileForManager/' + id, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
}
```

and it show me this response :

```
    [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(198563) [-1, -40, -1, -32, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 72, 0, 72, 0, 0, -1, -37, 0, 67, 0, 6, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 10, 16, 10, 10, 9, 9, 10, 20, 14, 15, 12, 16, 23, 20, 24, 24, 23, 20, 22, 22, 26, 29, 37, 31, 26, 27, 35, 28, 22, 22, 32, 44, 32, 35, 38, 39, 41, 42, 41, 25, 31, 45, 48, 45, 40, 48, 37, 40, 41, 40, -1, -37, 0, 67, 1, 7, 7, 7, 10, 8, 10, …]
[[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(198563) [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 72, 0, 72, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 6, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 10, 16, 10, 10, 9, 9, 10, 20, 14, 15, 12, 16, 23, 20, 24, 24, 23, 20, 22, 22, 26, 29, 37, 31, 26, 27, 35, 28, 22, 22, 32, 44, 32, 35, 38, 39, 41, 42, 41, 25, 31, 45, 48, 45, 40, 48, 37, 40, 41, 40, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 7, 7, 7, 10, 8, 10, …]
```

now i need covert this to image .

how can i do this ????

Comment: By "convert" you mean that you want to display the image with `<img />` tag?

Comment: @MoshFeu yes . . .

Comment: You can use that question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57490398/863110

Comment: Could you pls console.log to .toString() version of  the buffer and update your question with it ?