# Display an image file from Spring boot backend in javascript front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, jpeg

Can anyone guide me how to get the image data from the spring boot backend to a react front end?. Im basically saving the file in the server and by using the path saved in the db ill be retrieving the image.

So far I managed to get the file as an byte array to the front end and it can be checked in the network.
I need help displaying it in a `<img/>`
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an image stored as byte array in HTML/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756042/how-to-display-an-image-stored-as-byte-array-in-html-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes it kinda does.. can i set  the value to a state and then use that in the src? then i can avoid all the `document.getElementById` section right?

Comment: @HereticMonkey i tried them both. whats in the link and also what i suggested. It displays the broken image icon

Answer (score 2):

Recently worked on this topic. Sharing my experience

React

```
const [imageData, setImageData] = React.useState({});

  const getImage = (url) => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setImageData(response);
    });
  };

  const displayImage = () => {
    return (
      <div className="img">
        <img
          src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`}
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable Long id) {
       FileObject fileObject =  fileRepository.findById(id).get();
       byte[] base64encodedData = Base64.getEncoder().encode(fileObject.getData());
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + 
                 fileObject.getName() + "\"")
                .body(base64encodedData);
    }
```

Note : It is important that the image data is Base64 encoded in the Server

```
Base64.getEncoder().encode(fileObject.getData())
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote 100 times. Basically, what I did on my react project, is add the line data:image/jpeg;base64 . so, for dynamism in terms of image types, you could enable your API to return image type info and link it to the src link, i.e `data:image/${imageType};base64,${imageData}`