# How to change byte array taken from json to image

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, .net-core

I store images and data in database and i have .net Core API that sends back object which contains some data and array of images. How to show that image on page in angular? I tried using `FileReader` and its function `readAsDataURL` but i cant make it work and/or just can't convert images to blob.

**Object model that is sent back from API:**

```
    public class ControlPoint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Confirmation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public ControlPointType Type { get; set; }
}
```

**Image model:**

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ROWGUID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public int ControlPointId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Stream { get; set; }
}
```

**Angular control point model:**

```
export interface ControlPoint {
    id: number;
    location: string;
    confirmation: string;
    images: Photo[];
    type: ControlPointType;
}
```

**Angular Image model:**

```
export class Photo {
    fileName: string;
    dateAdded: Date;
    controlPointId: number;
    stream: any;
}
```

How should i handle this? I think i can't change response type to blob because i get whole object in json, not just images.

Comment: How you storing images? In the database? or in a folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an image stored as byte array in HTML/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756042/how-to-display-an-image-stored-as-byte-array-in-html-javascript)

Comment: Yup, thx. I was searching but this didnt showed up.